# Linking same table with two foreign keys in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-3.2

I have a table `match_schedules` which stores matches between two `teams`. There is table `teams` to store team information.

Columns of `match_schedules` are

```
+-----+---------+---------+-------+-------+
| id  | team_a  | team_b  | date  | venue |
+-----+---------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Since I have two columns `team_a` and `team_b` referencing `teams` table, I can't use `team_id` as foreign key in both columns.

Now, I want to associate these two columns with `teams` table so that I can easily retrieve associated data like

```
$matches = $this->MatchSchedules->find('all', [
  'contain' => [
      'Teams'
  ]
]);
```

I have tried this
**In TeamsTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('MatchSchedules', [
    'foreignKey' => 'team_a',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('MatchSchedules', [
    'foreignKey' => 'team_b',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

**In MatchSchedulesTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('Teams', [
    'foreignKey' => 'team_a'
]);
$this->hasMany('Teams', [
    'foreignKey' => 'team_b'
]);
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Change 'MatchSchedules' to 'MatchSchedulesA' and 'MatchSchedulesB', 'Teams' to 'TeamsA'and 'TeamsB'

Comment: this gives `MatchSchedules is not associated with Teams` on `$matches = $this->MatchSchedules->find('all', [ 'contain' => 'Teams' ]);`

Comment: this gives `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'teams_a' doesn't exist`.

Comment: read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Comment: this gives `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'TeamsA.team_a' in 'where clause' `  **SQL QUERY** `SELECT TeamsA.id AS `TeamsA__id`, TeamsA.title AS `TeamsA__title`, TeamsA.logo AS `TeamsA__logo`, FROM teams TeamsA WHERE TeamsA.team_a in (:c0,:c1)`

Comment: Please, Accept answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You did not properly set up associations

**TeamsTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('MatchSchedulesA', [
    'foreignKey' => 'team_a',
    'className' => 'MatchSchedules'
]);
$this->hasMany('MatchSchedulesB', [
    'foreignKey' => 'team_b',
    'className' => 'MatchSchedules'
]);
```

**In MatchSchedulesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('TeamsA', [
    'foreignKey' => 'team_a',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'className' => 'Teams'
]);
$this->belongsTo('TeamsB', [
    'foreignKey' => 'team_b',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'className' => 'Teams'
]);
```

and

```
$matches = $this->MatchSchedules->find('all', [
  'contain' => [
      'TeamsA',
      'TeamsB
  ]
]);
```

Is nice to be if you rename:

```
MatchSchedulesA to HomeMatches 
MatchSchedulesB to GuestMatches 
team_a to home_team 
team_b to guest_team 
TeamsA to HomeTeams 
TeamsB to GuestTeams
```